# Android - Crash on setAdapter()

Tags: android, eclipse, adapter

my app crashes when I set the adapter for a List View. Here is my Code:

MainActivity.java :

```java
package com.example.viewlist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView ;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                                      "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};  
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);

    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );

    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 

}
}
```

fragment_Main.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/mainListView">
</ListView>
```

simplerow.xml :

```js
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

I'm using Eclipse and the difficult thing is that i copied the code nearly 1:1 from the a source. The apk which was compiled from source by the orig Author is working. I don't know why, so I need your help! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post logcat logs..

Comment: nothing seems to be wrong with your code please post logcat

Comment: looks like the `ListView` is declared in `fragment_Main.xml` and you are setting `activity_main.xml` as your layout in `activity`

Comment: `R.layout.activity_main` , `fragment_Main.xml`

Comment: Make sure you are using proper overloaded constructor of ArrayAdapter, In your case parameters should be (context, int,string[]).

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Thank you. This was the Solution. I was blind to see it.

Answer (score 4):

what are these?

```
listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
listAdapter.add( "Eris" );
```

drop these and run the project again to see is it work or not

Comment: they are valid you can add items to the adapter itself

Comment: the simplerow.xml have 1 Textview so write those to String block